# Nested hash and rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, nested

I have to load from file a lot of clients with phonenumbers

my models Clients :name
has_many :telnumbers

Telnumbers :number, :comment

So I have done rake task

```
desc "Loads file clients from excell"
task :loadclientsfromfile do
require 'csv'  
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'  

csv_text = File.read('c:\ddd1.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  telnumbers = row.to_hash.slice("number","comment")
  raw = row.to_hash.slice("name")
  raw = raw.to_hash.symbolize_keys
  telnumbers = telnumbers.to_hash.symbolize_keys
  telnumber1 = {}
  telnumber1["0"] = telnumbers
  raw[:telnumbers_attributes] = telnumber1
  Client.create!(raw)
end
```

And my CSV file:

```
name,number,comment
Second CLient,2343262,home
```

I want to get the hash `{:name=>"Second Client", :telnumbers_attributes=>{"0"=>{:number=>"2343262",:comment=>"home"}}}`

But my code not like me. Help me please to DRY it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
desc "Loads file clients from excell"
task :load_clients_from_file do 
  file_path = 'c:\ddd1.csv'  
  lines = IO.readlines(file_path, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
  header = lines.shift.strip
  keys = header.split(/,/)
  lines.each do |line|
    values = line.strip.split(/,/)
    tel_hash = { "0" => {keys[1].to_sym => values[1], keys[2].to_sym => values[2]}}
    raw = {keys[0].to_sym => values[0], :telnumbers_attributes => tel_hash}
    Client.create!(raw)
  end
end
```

here the out put of the hash looks like below

```
{:name=>"Second CLient", :telnumbers_attributes=>{"0"=>{:number=>"2343262", :comment=>"home"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting way. My code works also, but I wanted to get it more simple ... In way I'll get it my memories.